# Same query, different execution time on MySQL 5.5 and 5.7. (MySQL 5.5 not using the index)

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, query-performance

For compatibility reasons, I had to downgrade a production database from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 5.5.

After moving to 5.5, I've noticed that this query has become MUCH slower, from like 200ms to like ~20 seconds of execution.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  `calendar`
INNER JOIN
  `spot` ON `spot`.`product` = `calendar`.`product`
        AND `spot`.`company_id` = `calendar`.`company_id`
INNER JOIN
  `detection` ON `detection`.`spot_id` = `spot`.`id`
WHERE `calendar`.`starts_at` = '2017-11-17'
  AND `calendar`.`user_id` = 73
  AND `detection`.`date` >= '2017-11-17'
  AND `detection`.`date` <= '2017-11-23'
```

Here's the EXPLAIN output for MySQL 5.5:

```
1 SIMPLE | calendar | ref starts_at_ends_at_index starts_at_ends_at_index 3 const 1204 | Using where
1 SIMPLE | spot ref PRIMARY,company_id_index,product_index | product_index | 302 calendar.product | 13 | Using where
1 SIMPLE | detection | ref spot_id_index,date_index | spot_id_index 48 | spot.Id | 80 | Using where
```

Here's the EXPLAIN output for MySQL 5.7:

```
1 SIMPLE | calendar | ref starts_at_ends_at_index starts_at_ends_at_index 3 const 1204 | Using where
1 SIMPLE | spot ref PRIMARY,company_id_index,product_index | product_index | 302 calendar.product | 13 | Using index condition; Using where
1 SIMPLE | detection | ref spot_id_index,date_index | spot_id_index 48 | spot.Id | 80 | Using where
```

The only difference I can see is that MySQL 5.7 uses: `Using index condition; Using where` on `product_index`, 5.5 don't.

I've tried to force the index usage, by specifying `USE INDEX(product_index)`, but nothing changed

Any suggestion?

EDIT:

Current useful indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `calendar` ADD INDEX `starts_at_ends_at_index` (`starts_at`, `ends_at`);

ALTER TABLE `spot` ADD INDEX `company_id_index` (`company_id`);

ALTER TABLE `spot` ADD INDEX `product_index` (`product`);

ALTER TABLE `detection` ADD INDEX `spot_id_index` (`spot_id`);

ALTER TABLE `detection` ADD INDEX `date_index` (`date`);
```

Comment: Database version updates often include better query optimization. (So, version downgrades can remove optimizations.) Your best bet for fixing this is to repeat your query-optimization work on the downgraded platform. What indexes do the tables have? Please [edit] your question to tell us.

Comment: @O.Jones Edited.

Comment: This seems to be an example of where ICP ("Using index condition") shines.  (But the real fix is to add better indexes; see O.Jones's Answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query filters `calendar` by two equality criteria, so those should appear in the same index as each other. It then uses the `product` column to access another table. So, put those three columns into one [compound index](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/). Try this:

```
 ALTER TABLE calendar ADD INDEX user_id_starts_at_product (user_id, starts_at, product);
```

Your query does a data range filter on `detection`, and also selects rows with particular values of `spot_id`. So try this compound index.

```
 ALTER TABLE detection ADD INDEX spot_id_date (spot_id, date);
```

Also try the compound index with the columns in the reverse order, and keep the index that gives you better performance.

```
 ALTER TABLE detection ADD INDEX date_spot_id (date, spot_id);
```

Try a compound index on `spot` to cover both filtering criteria (appearing on your ON clause).

```
  ALTER TABLE spot ADD INDEX company_id_product (company_id, product);
```

**Pro tip**: MySQL ordinarily can use only one index for each table per query (or subquery). So adding lots of single-column indexes is not generally a good way to make particular queries faster. Instead, adding compound indexes matching the requirements of your query is the way to go.  This is true for various database versions.

Comment: Adding to the Pro tip:  Put `=` columns first.

Comment: Good advice, wrong reasons.  If `detection` is used first, the order `(date, spot_id)` is better because it is 'covering'.  Else, `(spot_id, date)` is better so that the `=` comes first.

Answer (score 0):

I would try moving the where clause predicates that don't filter the calendar table into join predicates, if nothing else it helps with readability but can also help the engine to compile a more optimal plan.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    `calendar`
INNER JOIN `spot` 
    ON `spot`.`product` = `calendar`.`product` 
    AND `spot`.`company_id` = `calendar`.`company_id`
INNER JOIN `detection` 
    ON `detection`.`spot_id` = `spot`.`id`
    AND `detection`.`date` BETWEEN '2017-11-17' AND '2017-11-23'  
WHERE
    `calendar`.`starts_at` = '2017-11-17' 
    AND `calendar`.`user_id` = 73
```

It's also possible that the index needs rebuilding following the downgrade, you can do this for each table with the below.

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE `calendar`;
OPTIMIZE TABLE `spot`;
OPTIMIZE TABLE `detection`;
```

This does lock the tables whilst it's running though, so bear that in mind on a production DB.

Finally, is `spot`.`product` a foreign key of `calendar`.`product` or vice versa? Are they exactly the same Data Type?

Comment: I've tried your query and also the "optimize" statement, but there's no substantial change. the `product` field is a VARCHAR, containing the name of the product. (I haven't designed this database, and I have to keep it as-is since the client software depend on it) :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Optimizer ignores whether you put things in `ON` versus `WHERE`.

Comment: `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is rarely useful; don't bother.